# viewController and pushViewcontroller not working?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I am trying pushViewController in iOS.But the execution result is following

[image: My Fist view]

[image: Second View]

When i hit the button it will make a transition from view A to View B.
Here is my code for view A

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController

-(IBAction)next:(id)sender;

@end
```

in .m file

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
@interface ViewControllerA ()
@end

@implementation ViewControllerA
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    ViewControllerB *viewController=[[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
    viewController.string=@"tunvir";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
@end
```

in viewController B

```
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *string;

@end
```

In .m file

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB

@synthesize string=_string;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@end
```

In want to set the string in viewB to "tunvir" and load the object as viewB. but a lot of warning appears.Why this is happening and how to fix this?Thanks

Comment: What kind of warnings?

Comment: nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2013-05-14 14:55:36.881 TestBarDelegate[1687:11303] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2013-05-14 14:55:36.883 TestBarDelegate[1687:11303] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewControllerB: 0x7173f70>.

Comment: Do you have xib file for ViewControllerB???

Comment: no..i am working with storyboard.

Comment: Your code is working. Second screen get dark because of default view background set to black. Why you are getting so many warnings? Did u initialize the navigation controller properly in AppDelegate?

Comment: @TunvirRahmanTusher Did you get the solution ? I am facing the similar issue

Comment: @iOSDevJust follow any of the answer below.Both works fine.If my question is helpful to you then plz give an upvote.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only need to set the title for the navigationBar of the ViewControllerB'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Title for NavigationBar";
}
```

**EDIT** use this if ur using Storyboard

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" 
                              bundle:NULL]
UIViewController *viewControllerb = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewControllerb animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: causing exception and crash the program.

Comment: If you're using a Storyboard then why not use a segue instead of having to implement the pushViewController: yourself ...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using storyboard do like this..

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender 
{

ViewControllerB *viewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerB"];
viewController.string=@"tunvir";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Dont forget to give `StoryboardId` for the viewControllerB  as `viewControllerB`

Answer (score 0):

replace `ViewControllerB *viewController=[[ViewControllerB alloc]init];` with

```
ViewControllerB *viewController=[[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: causing exception and crash the program.

Comment: this might be because compiler cant find nib file for `@"ViewControllerB"`

Answer (score 0):

try below code...

```
 -(IBAction)next:(id)sender
    {
        ViewControllerB *viewController=[[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
        viewController.string=@"tunvir";
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: causing exception and crash the program.

Comment: do you have xib of ViewControllerB? and why you are using viewController.string=@"tunvir"; this line ?

Answer (score 0):

Yo uare not initialising properly .Use

```
ViewControllerB *viewController=[[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerBXIbFileNAme" bundle:nil];
```

instead of

```
ViewControllerB *viewController=[[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
```